# vue.js How to call a function inside a for loop and pass the current item?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Using vue.js 2, inside a for loop, I need to render a row only if the current iterated item passes some test.

The test is complex so a simple `v-if="item.value == x"` wont do.

I've written a function named `testIssue` that accepts the item and returns true or false and tried to use that is a`v-if` like this:

```
<template v-for="issue in search_results.issues">
  <tr v-if="testIssue(issue)">
     ....
  </tr>
</template>


var releaseApp = new Vue({
  el: '#release-app',
  methods: {
    testIssue: function(issue) {
      console.log(issue);
      console.log('test');
    },
  },
  mounted: function() {},
  data: {
    search_results: {
      issues: []
    },
  }
});
```

However, `testIssue` is never called.

If I change the line to `<tr v-if="testIssue">`, the function is called but then I dont have the `issue` variable that I need to test.

I also tried `<tr v-if="releaseApp.testIssue(issue)">`

How can I call a function in a `v-if` declaration inside a for loop and pass the current item?

Answer (score 3):

First of all you can't do `v-for` on a `<template>` tag as you can have only one element per template.

You can add a v-if on the same element as v-for, and it just won't render the element that doesn't pass the v-if. If it's a spearate component per row then it's better to do v-for in parent component and pass the issue by props to child component.

Parent:

```
<child-comp v-for="issue in search_results.issues" v-if="testIssue(issue)">
</child-comp>
```

Child:

```
<template>
  <tr>
    {{issue}}
  </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: Seeing the code @delightedDOD is not using single file components where template element is present. he just doing it the plain javascript way. So `v-for` on template tag is possible as it is inside some parent element which has id `#release-app`. See this fiddle ( https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/50pgoo5u/3/)

Comment: Then yes, he can do it also without child components.

Comment: what do you mean by without child components

Comment: inside his template elementt he just wants `<tr>` to not be displayed. By placing `v-if` on the template element itself will conditionally display the whole template element, i think he just wants to conditionally display `<tr>` inside template element.

Answer (score 2):

Your scenario works with a similar example in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/50pgoo5u/2/).

But you can try it this way also:

You can create a [custom directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html) named `v-hide` and pass `issue` to it as its value.

Then in the directive you can test for `testIssue()` and set the particular element's display to none

```
<template v-for="issue in search_results.issues">
  <tr v-hide="issue">
     ....
  </tr>
</template>


var releaseApp = new Vue({
  el: '#release-app',
  directive:{
    hide: {
        bind(el, binding, Vnode){
            var vm = Vnode.context;
            var issue = binding.value;
            if(vm.testIssue(issue)){
                el.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    testIssue: function(issue) {
      console.log(issue);
      console.log('test');
    },
  },
  mounted: function() {},
  data: {
    search_results: {
      issues: []
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: You're right that fiddle does work, and I was sure I had done this before without issue, that proves it. There must be something else going on in my code causing my issue. Thank you, gonna dig some more

Answer (score 1):

You can also try creating a computed item that makes use of the `filter` method so that you have an array where all elements pass the test function before actually rendering (in this case, just returning odd numbers):

https://codepen.io/aprouja1/pen/BZxejL

```
computed:{
    compIssues(){
      return this.search_results.issues.filter(el => el%2===1)
    }
  },
```